# Code128 Barcode in Adobe Acrobat Form

Tags: adobe, barcode, acrobat, code128

I want to create a Code128 barcode in an Adobe Acrobat Form. There is an option to add a barcode, but the only supported formats are PDF417, QR and DataMatrix.

Is there any way to add a simple 1D barcode instead? Does this need to be done using JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you'll need is access to a suitable code 128 bar code font that allows at least editable embedding. You can then use it with a regular text form field and use JavaScript to set the field value correctly. This involves including the start/stop characters, calculating and including the check digit, selecting the code set, and possibly code set shifting. The hardest part can be finding the font.